# Can you build a model based on coefficients with Pr>0.05?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, cross-validation

I have a data set of 3 independent variables and 28 cases (sample size). I have tried both train-test linear regression and k-fold cross validation for making the linear regression model. In both methods I get coefficients for my variables that have a Pr> 0.05. Given that I have R-squared value >0.9, can I use this model? If the coefficients have Pr values > 0.05 can I report them?

```
> summary(model1)

Call:
lm(formula = data1$survival ~ ., data = train1)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-44.678 -25.424  -6.127  23.094  72.827 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 55.878837  12.312291   4.538 0.000134 ***
X1          -0.028698   0.055040  -0.521 0.606871    
X2          -0.697045   1.211960  -0.575 0.570550    
X4          -0.005916   0.038547  -0.153 0.879307    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

and the RMSE:

```
    > RMSE1
[1] 3.172029e-14
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should not purposefully hide information, especially, based on p-values. Building a model using p-values as a criterion is now well documented to be pretty bad in many ways.

Comment: Thank you. I understood from your answer that I must report the P values, but what I'm asking is that is this model in general reliable and worthy of being reported? Considering that I have a good R-squared (not the R-squared above).